# Limit of continuous function with lower bound but without a minimum when $x \to \infty$

Tags: calculus

Let $f: [0, \infty) \to R$ continuous function, that has lower limit:

$m = inf \{ f([0, \infty))\}$

but doesn't have global minimum.

Is it true that $lim_{x \to \infty}=m$? If yes, how to prove that?

Comment: lower limit = liminf?

Comment: @Math_QED yes (15 chars)

Comment: @AlonGubkin Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You can prove by contradiction that if $$lim_{x \to \infty}\neq m$$

then by [EVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) $f$ should have a global minimum.

Comment: But EVT is only true for closed bounds, isn't it? I can't use it for $[0,\infty)$

Comment: You can also extend for continuos functions in [0,\infty)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: We have that $f(0)=a>m$, if $lim_{x \to \infty}=L \neq m$ we have that L>m, thus exist $x_0 f(x_0)=b$ with $m<b<L$ then $f(x) in [0,x_0]$ has a minimum that is a global minimum for $f$.

Comment: Why is the minimum in $[0, x_0]$ is the global minimum for $f$?

Comment: because for the definition of limit we can find $x_0$ such that for each $x\ge x_0$ $f(x)\ge b$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still don't understand. The definition of limit is that for each $\epsilon>0$ we can find $x_0$ such that for each $x > x_0$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. What $\epsilon$ did you choose here? Can you please write a more noob answer? Thank you again very much!